# Make excel remember references

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a worksheet named B that has references to worksheet A like this:

```
'sheet A'!A1
'sheet A'!C1
'sheet A'!F1
'sheet A'!G1
...
```

But now I need to add some new and old lines to the source from a worksheet that says:

```
A1
B1
F1
H1
```

Manually adding these lines will take too much time because I have to do a lot of them on a fairly regular basis.

Is there a way for me to copy/paste this new sheet onto the source whilst my references won't get pushed around (so that the reference to A1 will always stay on A1 even if I add or remove a line).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` for this.

the below will always point to cell `A1`:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1))
```

And you can even point to a specific cell in another sheet like below:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(1,1))
```

`ADDRESS` makes use of cell reference, so 1,1 is `A1`, however, these numbers too can be replaced with other formulas, such as `ROW`, `COLUMN` etc. to enable a dynamic approach of setting a place in the spreadsheet, that can stay locked to a column or row when new rows or columns are added.

Was this what you was looking for ?